# Why does Joi's dress change frequently?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

In *Blade Runner 2049*, after Officer K had reached home, he talks to Joi via holograms.

[image]

We can see her dress changes frequently during the conversation. Why so?

Comment: Maybe she's trying to fit K's mood ? (I don't remember this particular scene).

Comment: Because he bought the Thousand Outfits in-app purchase. It was expensive, but it said it was the best value.

Comment: Because changing clothes is fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1. To fit K's mood

As pointed out so poignantly<sup>@</sup>, Joi is changing her clothes to try and suit K's mood. Joi is a pleasure bot, she's designed purely to make sure her 'owner' is happy. She does a damn good job at it.

One of her means of achieving this is by 'looking' as pleasing to K as she can. She reads his moods and emotional cues<sup>#</sup>, and adjusts to suit.

At this point, K's mood is tarting to go off the radar, he's starting to drift from his baseline, this is foreshadowing as Joi's connection to K is incredibly deep.

## 2. To suit *her* mood

You can see that when she goes from the white outfit to the black one<sup>$</sup>, it is synced to her change of stance and demeanor; she's changing her look to suit her intent. Yes, this is ultimately to suit K's mood.

## 3. To show us how advanced she is

The out-of-universe reason for this is to give us clues about her being. She's an incredibly advanced piece of technology. This ties into her ability as a chameleon and gives us a bit of foreshadowing of her true nature and later events with Mariette.

The other part of this is that it shows us how *unreal* she truly is. It's blatantly obvious that she's a machine. Yet, why do we still feel her reality and come to believe that she truly loves K? That's why I think she was one of the most well-written characters!

---

<sup>**@** [In the comments by @Max](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179247/why-does-jois-dress-change-frequently#comment484221_179247)</sup>

<sup>**#** Yes, he *does* have emotional cues, albeit incredibly subtle.</sup>

<sup>**$** As a dude, that is the extent of my fashion knowledge</sup>